# Getting multiple related models together

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In my Laravel app, I have three models, `User`, `Course` and `CourseScore`. I want to get all courses for an specific user with his score. something like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: first_name,
  corses: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'course one',
      score: 17, // this is what i need for every course,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'course two',
      score: 19, // this is what i need for every course,
    },
  ]
}
```

Here are my `Models`:

`User`

```
<?php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function courseScores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CourseScore::class);
    }

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class);
    }
}
```

`Course`

```
<?php
class Course extends Model
{
    public function courseScores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CourseScore::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

`CourseScore`

```
<?php
class CourseScore extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'course_scores';

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

And of course, please let me know if the relations are incorrect.

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: @MamaWin I wanna get the list of all user courses with the score of each course.

Comment: Have you tried to use `DB::table('Your table name')`

Comment: @MamaWin I'm trying to achieve this using `eloquent`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you can do something like this,

in your **User** model

```
  public function courses(){
    return $this->hasMany(Course::class); // changed belongsToMany to hasMany
  }
```

in your **Course** model

```
  public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class); // changed belongsToMany to belongsTo
  }
```

In your controller

```
 $usersData = User::with('courses.courseScores')->get();
 dd($usersData);
```

I dont fully understand your table structure so Im assuming you have multiple row of Scores for single Course (One to Many).
If the relationship is one is to one then add in your **Course** Model

```
public function courseScores(){
    return $this->hasOne(CourseScore::class); //changed hasMany to hasOne
}
```

Comment: regardless of your table relationships. I think the one in Controller is the you are looking for.

Comment: If we say User `hasMany` Courses, then `courses` table should have a `user_id` column. While I think it should be a many to many relationship. Users attends to many courses (belongs to many courses) and courses have many `courseScores`. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this

```
   $val = DB::table('course as c')
        ->join('user as u', 'u.id','c.id')
        -join('courseScore as cs','u.id','cs.id')
        ->get();
```

Then just `dd($val)` to see what value it shown